# Problem with loading fonts in html on UITextView in iOS

Tags: android, html, ios, swift, fonts

I have an `HTML script` that needs to be displayed inside of a webview in `Android` and in an `UITextView` in `iOS`. This script uses multiple fonts.
When declaring the fonts in `Android` I used the following script:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'myfont';
    src:url("file:///android_asset/fonts/myfont.ttf")
    }
```

and it worked perfectly fine. 
In ios, however, I was unable to find the correct solution for setting the source path for the fonts.
I tried the following:

```
    src:url("myfont.ttf")

    src:url("myfont.ttf")

    src:url("file:///fonts/myfont.ttf")

    src:url("file:myfont.ttf")
```

Do you know how it should be set for `iOS`

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention the correct font family name and that's it. No need to specify the `src`. Just make sure to add it in your `Info.plist` file under key `<key>UIAppFonts</key>` like so:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Lato-Black.ttf</string>
</array>
```

> How to find font family name?

You might think that the font family name is the name of the file itself. But it is not. Have a look at the below screenshot

[image]

The file name is different but the font book shows something else. The title in the font book application is your font family name. To denote different weights of the font, use `-Regular`, `-Bold`, etc.

Then in your css you can directly use

```
span {
    font-family: "MathJax_Math-Regular"
}
```

and your font should be applied

Comment: I tried it at it does not work. The fonts are added to the app and work ok in rest(when  used on label and buttons)

Comment: are you adding the css properly to the html you are trying to show in webview?

Comment: it is correct added because it works on Android, the only change here is the path to the font